# How to display password policy information for a user (Ubuntu)?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, password-management

[Ubuntu Documentation > Ubuntu 9.04 > Ubuntu Server Guide > Security > User Management](https://help.ubuntu.com/9.04/serverguide/C/user-management.html) states that there is a default minimum password length for Ubuntu:

> By default, Ubuntu requires a minimum
>   password length of 4 characters

Say the password is to be modified by the user using `passwd`. Is there a command for displaying the current password policies for a user (such as the `chage` command displays the password expiration information for a specific user)?

```
> sudo chage -l SomeUserName
Last password change                                : May 13, 2010
Password expires                                    : never
Password inactive                                   : never
Account expires                                     : never
Minimum number of days between password change      : 0
Maximum number of days between password change      : 99999
Number of days of warning before password expires   : 7
```

This is rather than examining various places that control the policy and interpreting them since the process could contain errors. A command that reports the composed policy would be used to check the policy setting steps.

Comment: Please provide a **valid** reason for migrating valid Super User questions. If a question does not receive an answer on Super User after a period of time we will be willing to migrate it, but we are **not** migrating valid questions without a valid reason. Also note all further flags to such effect will be ignored on the above basis.

Comment: I would post the question in the Ubuntu site rather than on SU if I had known it existed. So, should I repost this question on the Ubuntu site rather than having it migrated to the most focused site?

Answer (score 6):

The OP confuses two different questions: *policy* and *password length*.

As already stated by @BillThor, password length is dealt with by the PAM module, under the not truly auspicious keyword `obscure`, in the file /etc/pam.d/common-password, which contains the following line:

```
 password        [success=1 default=ignore]      pam_unix.so obscure sha512
```

The `obscure` keyword stands for (according to *man pam_unix*):

```
 obscure
       Enable some extra checks on password strength. These checks are based on the "obscure" checks in the
       original shadow package. The behavior is similar to the pam_cracklib module, but for
       non-dictionary-based checks. The following checks are implemented:

       Palindrome
           Verifies that the new password is not a palindrome of (i.e., the reverse of) the previous one.

       Case Change Only
           Verifies that the new password isn't the same as the old one with a change of case.

       Similar
           Verifies that the new password isn't too much like the previous one.

       Simple
           Is the new password too simple? This is based on the length of the password and the number of
           different types of characters (alpha, numeric, etc.) used.

       Rotated
           Is the new password a rotated version of the old password? (E.g., "billy" and "illyb")
```

The prescription by `obscure` can be overridden as follows: in /etc/pam.d/common-password, re-write the line above as

```
 password        [success=1 default=ignore]      pam_unix.so obscure sha512 minlen=20
```

or whatever you like.

Finding exactly where the minimum length password is defined requires diving into the depths of pam:

```
  # apt-cache search pam_unix.so
    libpam-modules - Pluggable Authentication Modules for PAM
  # apt-get source libpam-modules
```

... and then to find where the minimum passord length is defined:

```
  # grep -rl UNIX_MIN_PASS_LEN
    modules/pam_unix/support.h
    modules/pam_unix/support.c
    debian/patches-applied/007_modules_pam_unix
    debian/patches-applied/055_pam_unix_nullok_secure
```

Perusing the debian patches you will see that the parameter UNIX_MIN_PASS_LEN (the 27th possible parameter) corresponds to a variable called **minlen**, which is set in /modules/pam_unix/support.c. However, one of the debian patches fixes `pass_min_len`: the file debian/patches-applied/007_modules_pam_unix contains the lines:

```
 -       int pass_min_len = 0;
 +       int pass_min_len = 6;
```

and the file debian/Changelog specifies:

> - Further cleanups of 007_modules_pam_unix -- don't use a global variable
>     for pass_min_len, don't gratuitously move the length checking into the
>     "obscure" checks, and internationalize the error strings.

I always disliked PAM, and for this reason: to locate a trivial parameter like the minimum password length, it obliges you to look into the source code.

The information displayed by `chage -l username` is instead completely contained in the /etc/shadow file: The [Man page](http://linux.die.net/man/5/shadow) states:

> shadow is a file which contains the password information for the system's accounts and optional aging information.

The fields of each entry are:

> Login name, encrypted password, date of last password change, minimum password age, maximum password age, password warning period, password inactivity period, account expiration date, plus a reserved field for future use.

Just to double check, an `strace` of the `chage` command shows which files are opened,

```
 # strace -e trace=open -f chage -l myusername
   open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
   open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
   open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
   open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
   open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3                                                                                                                                                                                                               
   open("/proc/filesystems", O_RDONLY)     = 3                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
   open("/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
   open("/etc/passwd", O_RDONLY|O_NOCTTY|O_NONBLOCK|O_NOFOLLOW) = 3                                                                                                                                                                                                               
   open("/etc/shadow", O_RDONLY|O_NOCTTY|O_NONBLOCK|O_NOFOLLOW) = 4                                                                                                                                                                                                               
   open("/usr/share/locale/locale.alias", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 5                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
   open("/usr/share/locale/en_US/LC_MESSAGES/shadow.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such      file or directory)                                                                                                                                                                        
   open("/usr/share/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/shadow.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)                                                                                                                                                                           
   open("/usr/share/locale-langpack/en_US/LC_MESSAGES/shadow.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)                                                                                                                                                               
   open("/usr/share/locale-langpack/en/LC_MESSAGES/shadow.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)                                                                                                                                                                  
   open("/etc/localtime", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 5                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
   Last password change                                    : mag 05, 2014                                                                                                                                                                                                         
   Password expires                                        : never                                                                                                                                                                                                                
   Password inactive                                       : never                                                                                                                                                                                                                
   Account expires                                         : never                                                                                                                                                                                                                
   Minimum number of days between password change          : 0                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
   Maximum number of days between password change          : 99999                                                                                                                                                                                                                
   Number of days of warning before password expires       : 7                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
   +++ exited with 0 +++
```

Answer (score 2):

THe policy is found in /etc/pam.d/common-password.  Default policy is obscure which is documented in the pam_unix man page.  You may want to install pam_cracklib  and add some addition policies.   Password changes by root generally avoid policies.

If you are not using pam to verify the new password, then the policy will belong to the tool used to change the password.  This can happen if you are using LDAP or another external password database and changing the password directly in the database.

Comment: Added to the question that passwd is the tool to be used.

Comment: If that is the case, /etc/pam.d/common-passwd is where the policy gets inserted.  pam_unix provides the default policy.

I don't think a policy display tool exists.  It would need to know all the possible pam modules that apply.  Considering that these are possibly user-written, only some policies would be possible.